# Problem with using OPENROWSET for executing SQL query from files

Tags: sql-server, backend

I use this query to load SQL command from files:

```
DECLARE @FileContents  VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @FileContents = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK'E:\SQLQuery5.sql', single_blob) x;

EXECUTE(@FileContents)
```

But what I get from this is in a single row and this interferes in query execution, because of "GO".

What is loaded into SQL:

```
USE [TEst db]  
GO 

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[User_details]    Script Date: 4/14/2020 8:16:11 AM ******/  
SET ANSI_NULLS ON  
GO  
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  
GO  

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User_details]
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,   
    [Role] [varchar](50) NULL,   
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,    
    [Status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,   
    [Logid] [int] NOT NULL  
) ON [PRIMARY]  
GO  

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[User_login]    Script Date: 4/14/2020 8:16:11 AM ******/  
SET ANSI_NULLS ON  
GO  
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  
GO  

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User_login]
(   
     [Id] [int] NOT NULL,   
     [Username] [varchar](100) NULL,   
     [Password] [varchar](100) NULL,   
     [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,   
     [Date] [datetime] NULL,   
     [status] [tinyint] NULL,   
     [logid] [int] NOT NULL  
) ON [PRIMARY]  
GO
```

The error message I get is

> Incorrect Syntax near GO

because the SQL reads this as one single line.

Any way to get the result I want without removing "GO"?

Contents of SqlQuery5.sql

```
USE [TEst db]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[User_details]    Script Date: 4/14/2020 8:16:11 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User_details](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Role] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Logid] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[User_login]    Script Date: 4/14/2020 8:16:11 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User_login](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Username] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [status] [tinyint] NULL,
    [logid] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

`GO` statement causes an error in the dynamic queries because ;

> SQL Server provides commands that are not Transact-SQL statements, but
>   are recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server
>   Management Studio Code Editor. These commands can be used to
>   facilitate the readability and execution of batches and scripts.
>
> GO signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL
>   Server utilities.

As a result, `GO` statement is not a T-SQL command and you can not use like to

```
EXEC ('USE TEst db GO')
```

because it will return an error.

Particularly your question, you can change the

```
USE [TEst db] 
GO
```

the statement as likes below;

```
 USE [TEst db];
```

Your query will run on that database.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to replace the `GO` with `EXEC` during the execution.

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @FileContents VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @FileContents = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK'D:\Test\SQLQuery5.sql', single_blob) x;
SET @sql = 'EXEC (''' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@FileContents, '''', ''''''), 'GO', '''); EXEC(''') + ''');'
EXECUTE(@sql)
```